# Open source implementations of the medial axis transform for vector shapes

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, mesh-generation, geometry

Are there any open source implementations of the [medial axis transform](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs597D/lectures/medial.pdf) for vector shapes?

I have searched without finding any useful results. It seems that [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) library doesn't have it implemented nor the [deal.ii](https://www.dealii.org/) library.

Are there any impelementation?

---

**Note**: Some examples of shapes I am interested in: Polygons with holes. The holes are either circular or polygonal.

Comment: Do you have vector or raster data?

Comment: @Richard: I have updated the quesiton

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69237155/752843) help you?

Comment: @Richard: I am not sure if that address the medial axis. I think that answer concerns the straight skeleton (which is different from medial axis). Additionally, straight skeleton is already available in CGAL without the need to directly to compute the voronoi diagram.

Comment: That answer doesn't include the word "skeleton" anywhere. CGAL doesn't (or didn't as of a year or so ago, not sure about now) have a medial axis implementation. You extract the medial axis from the Voronoi diagram.

Comment: @Richard: I have tried your example. but I have several questions: is that really medial axis or straight skeleton (yes you didn't mention that but it look like it is). Does the answer support polygons with holes?

Comment: That asnwer says it's medial axis. Unless you can better explain why it might not be, I'm not sure how to help you. I see the word "holes" quite a few places in the answer, so it probably supports holes as well.

Comment: @Richard: I have found this on [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_skeletonization/index.html) But I am not able to get it to work due to compilation errors